# VSIX Visual studio extension project template Creation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I have a VSIX Visual Studio 2019 Extension that should add a project template to visual studio. To do this I used FlavouredProjectBase and FlavouredProjectFactory. The Classes look like this:

Project class:

```
class LugiaUIProject : FlavoredProjectBase
{

    public LugiaUIProject(IServiceProvider site)
    {

    }
}
```

Factory Class:

```
[Guid(LugiaUIProjectPackage.LugiaUIProjectFactoryString)]
internal class LugiaUIProjectFactory : FlavoredProjectFactory
{
    private LugiaUIProjectPackage lugiaUIProjectPackage;

    public LugiaUIProjectFactory(LugiaUIProjectPackage pkg)
    {
        lugiaUIProjectPackage = pkg;
    }

    protected override object PreCreateForOuter(object outerProject)
    {
        return new LugiaUIProject();
    }

    protected override void CreateProject(string fileName, string location, string name, uint flags, ref System.Guid projectGuid, out System.IntPtr project, out int canceled)
    {
        //??
    }
}
```

The Registration of the project seems to work fine, since the template shows up in the template list when creating a new project:
[image]

But I cant get the creation of the project to work. When I select the template it just throws an error.  If there is a breakpoint in the `CreateProject` override, it gets hit, but the project does not get generated. I unfortunatelydid not find any ressources / Documentation about "FlavouredProject" creation. Can anyone explain to me what is missing / what I am doing wrong here?
Or is this "FlavouredProject" method deprecated?

Comment: Could you please [provide a Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with us? We cannot reproduce it in our side.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Hello Perry, thank you for your comment. I uploaded the solution to Git. Check it out here: https://github.com/colosso/VSIXTest

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are encountering this error is because your project template is missing a couple things. Namely a project file (.csproj or similar), as well as a .vstemplate.

One thing to consider here; is that you want you'll likely want your project template to be deployed using the same .VSIX that installs your custom project flavor. So you should consider creating an actual project template project. Then reference that project from your VSIX project with a Project to Project reference, and and include it as an asset in your .vsixmanifest.

Using the Project Template wizard to create the initial project template, will ensure you get a project file, as well as a .vsixmanifest. Though you will need to modify the .csproj to use your project flavor. Namely, you'll need to ensure your project flavor's guid is added to the  tag in your .csproj file. Otherwise, the project will still just be stock C# based project. :-)

There is a [somewhat dated custom project type sample](https://github.com/EdDore/VSXArcana/tree/master/SimpleProject) I posted a number of years ago that implements a custom project type (not a project flavor), but it also included a project and item template, similar to what you are trying to do. And while it was written for an earlier version of VS, would probably still serve as a viable example /wrt implementing a project template to go along with your custom project flavor.

Also worth reading:

- [Getting started with the VSIX Project template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-the-vsix-project-template?view=vs-2019)

Sincerely,

Comment: You might want to test your answers before you post them. 

Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))

Comment: For the record I do test my answers before I post them. I actually reviewed the code in question and noted several things that needed fixing. The original poster certainly found the response useful. I'm guessing your issue is not related to the original posters codebase, so perhaps you can post your own SO inquiry, and provide some details as to how to go about reproducing your issue for further comment.

Comment: I'm using the OP's code (github.com/colosso/VSIXTest) and it is generating an Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT)) just after the InitializeAsync finishes.